# MySQL Multi Registration Form to be Backup and Restore

Tags: php, mysql, backup, restore

I have registration form, which exactly same for several location.
Each of them has REG column, which this field is unique for each row.
Basically each data input have different REG number for it, this auto increment.
This form has same table for each different location.
However, we have one central location which pull all the database from several location.
This center have duty to manipulate and populate all those database.

Let's say, I have 3 location, A, B and C. All those using same database structure to save the database. What I need for help here, how I must change or configure the database table or column so I can "restore" each same database from different location into one single database on the central location. If the structure is same, then the previous data will be replace by the new one when restore / add to the database in the central location. I have column called "CODE" which stored specific hard code for each location, it just simple character either A, B or C base on where the location of the database saved.

So, at the specific time, from 3 different location, the form table will be backup and send to central. And there, it will be restore or add to the database to be populate all from those 3 locations.

Any idea and little help please?

Here the database layout I would like to be done:

[image: http://s12.postimg.org/ius4r8n6l/sshot_196.png]

Answer (score 0):

Create database `Backup` with the same structure. After that add a column to each table named `db_from`. Insert it into the primary key (old key=id, new=db_from,id). And when backing up specify the db name.

UPDATE: When you have tables

```
Location A
----------------
|ID | code| reg|
----------------
|  1|  AAA|  12|
|  2|  qwr|  43!
----------------

Location B
----------------
|ID | code| reg|
----------------
|  1|  BBB|  32|
|  2|  qwF|  53!
----------------

your backup should be

Backup
--------------------
|Loc|ID | code| reg|
--------------------
|  A|  1|  AAA|  12|
|  A|  2|  qwr|  43!
|  B|  1|  BBB|  32|
|  B|  2|  qwF|  53!
--------------------
```

Comment: I want all those 3 database "merge" to single database in the central location. Those 3 databases have same structure and fields. Where that "Backup" database should be create? And the REG column is a unique at the each location actually, since if we want to search, it will be REG number column.

Comment: You want to merge them in the central location so `Backup` will be there. If you have uniq key for _each table_ from the databases you want to merge there will be no need of additional field

Comment: But, the field of REG which is Unique at the several location, contain the same data. Let say, REG is always start with number 1, and all those location start at the same number, 1. So, the REG always have same data incrementally. That's why I'm in the middle of confusing how to manage that. Do I need another column or else.

Comment: So you must add a column to specify the origin. It may be number (or string). And you must alter the primary key in the `Backup` database to avoid duplicate keys with the same IDs from different locations.

Comment: Here the layout of the database I would like to be done. http://s12.postimg.org/ius4r8n6l/sshot_196.png

Comment: The problem for is I have REG column on each tables, same content. Just like my illustrate above. So, those three tables has content same each one.